# Pre-written progress indicators in Winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, progress-indicator

In `.NET` (Winforms), are they are any pre-written progress indicators to indicate that a process is waiting for completion for an unknown time?

I realise the `hour-glass` pointer can always be used, but is there anything more elaborate available?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're asking about the [ProgressBar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.aspx).

Comment: With [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) set to [`ProgressBarStyle.Marquee`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx)

Comment: Not really. I was after something that would just be a single function call like `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: @CJ7 I'd guess you can put it as the only control in a small form, and display the form as a modal or modeless dialog.